# Connection between ceil and round

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have two rounding functions.

The first is `ceil`, which always finds the smallest integer that is at least as large as the input. E.g. `ceil(0) = 0`, `ceil(0.1) = 1`, `ceil(0.5) = 1`, `ceil(0.9) = 1`.

The second is `round`, which always finds the integer closest to the input. For the middle (.5), it is defined as returning the next larger integer.  E.g. `round(0) = 0`, `round(0.1) = 0`, `round(0.5) = 1`, `round(0.9) = 1`.

Is there a connection between them that allows to substitute `ceil` by `round`?

Like `ceil(x) = g(round(f(x)))` for some functions `f`, `g` that do not contain `ceil`? Do such functions exist?

I only care about nonnegative numbers as input for `ceil` and `round`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the given rounding rule for half integers, your best bet is

$$\text{ceil}(x)=-\text{round}\left(-{1\over2}-x\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$\text {round}(x)=\text {ceil}\left(x-\frac {1}{2}\right)$$
But that rounds $.5$ down to $0$. If you want it to round up you have
$$\text {round}(x)=\text {floor}\left(x+\frac {1}{2}\right)$$
We also have that
$$\text {round}\left(x+\frac {1}{2}\right)=\text {ceil}(x)$$
But that assumes $.5$ rounds down.